# C "warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type" when function has an array as an argument

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, function-pointers

I am trying to get an array of pointer functions to work. However, I have noticed that, I get an error when one of the arguments of the function is an array type. I have no idea why I keep getting the error

Error message

```
warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
 void (*p[1])(int, int, int) = { mini };
```

Code

```
// function prototype
void min(int row, int col, const int arr[row][col]);


void(*p[1])(int, int, const int) = { min}; // error happens here

int main() {

// rest of code

}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Your code has unbalanced parentheses. Fix them.

Comment: they're all fixed now

Comment: What is the error that you get? Add the exact error from the compiler (copy-and-paste) as part of the question.

Comment: @crayzeewulf 
ArraysofPointers.c:15:33: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
 void (*p[1])(int, int, int) = { mini };

Comment: The third parameter of `min` is an array. The third parameter of the function pointers you are trying to store is `const int`. They are not the same.

Comment: I removed the [c++] tag for you, since the declaration of `min` is valid C but invalid C++.

Comment: @crayzeewulf  How can I represent the third parameter as an array?

Comment: @FsimulatorX See answer

Comment: An array of size 1 like the `p` you are trying to define is an odd creature — you don't often use arrays of size 1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function type you are trying to declare as the target of the element type of your array has as its third parameter a 2D, variable-length array of `const int`.  In your array declaration, however, you try to declare it as a single `const int`.  These are not compatible.

The clearest way to declare it would be like this:

```
void(*p[1])(int, int, const int[*][*]) = { min };
```

or like this:

```
void(*p[1])(int, int, const int[][*]) = { min };
```

.  The two are equivalent.  The `*` in the array dimension indicates a VLA of unknown size -- unknown because it depends on other arguments.  The first dimension (only) of an array parameter can always be omitted, and often I prefer to omit it, but in this case I prefer the first declaration, because even though the compiler ignores the first array dimension, it is clear to human readers that that, too, is a variable dimension.

Comment: Is it not the case that any actual parameter will be passed as `const int **` - a double pointer? I have never heard of the possibility for a function to receive an array as such as a parameter.

Comment: No, @Roflcopter4.  The argument passed will be a pointer to an array, which is not at all the same thing as a double pointer.  You can find numerous questions about that elsewhere on SO.

Comment: Copying the parameters of `min()` also works: `void(*p[1])(int row, int col, const int arr[row][col]) = {min};`. This might be easier to read for some perhaps, though misleading. Do you see any issue with this @JohnBollinger?

Answer (score 2):

You have `const int` for the function pointer and `int [][]` for your function, these are not the same. You must use `const int (*)[]` instead.

Your error will go away if you correctly declare `void(*p[1])(int, int, const int)` as:

```
void(*p[1])(int, int, const int (*)[]) = {min};
```

Comment: Does your code compiles after this change? On my machine (gcc on Win8) I get other errors - undefined reference that can be resolved with adding a body to the function and changing the name so it won't be confused with a macro with that same name

Comment: Why use the silly empty array notation like that? They are pointers, writing `int [] []` is just not only extra typing but misleading to beginners like the OP to the point of almost being a flat out lie. There is no array here.

Comment: @Roflcopter4 Well the OP has an array of arrays in their question. How would you propose the edit? This seems nitpicky.

Comment: @CIsForCookies This compiles for me fine. https://repl.it/repls/PoorModestDrawing

Comment: So you do add a function body! this is critical to the compilation process!

Comment: @Rivasa It certainly is nitpicky; this is just that one little nit that has always mostly just confused me. There's no reason to do it that way. What's wrong with `void((*p)[1])(int, int, const int **) = {min};`?

Comment: @Roflcopter4 What's the reason to do it your way? What's wrong with my way? This seems to be a preference choice. I did it this way because it's how I thought of it at first. That's all.

Comment: @Rivasa, there's no reason whatever to do it with a double pointer, because that's *wrong*.  The compiler ought to emit the same complaint about that variant that it does for the OP's original.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yet it doesn't? Why is that? It makes no complaint, and I would appreciate it if you can educate me on the difference between `const int (*)[]` and `const int[*][*]`

Comment: @Rivasa, I'm talking about (not) using `const int **`.  That means something different.

Comment: For the record, there is only a little practical difference between `const int (*)[]` and `const int [*][*]` and `const int [][*]` and `const int (*)[*]`.  The first is a pointer to an *incomplete* array type compatible with the actual parameter type of the function.  It can be used outside of a function parameter list, too.  The other three can be used only inside a function's parameter list, and in that context they each declare a pointer to a VLA with unspecified dimension, which is nevertheless a *complete* type.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Seems about time for me to fall on my sword here. You're right, they are entirely different types. My apologies to everyone for my ignorance. Now all I have to do is figure out what in god's name is actually being passed into a paramater of a VLA type.

Answer (score 2):

Compiler is giving this warning message because you are trying to initialize first member of array pointer `p` of type `void (*)(int, int, const int)` with `min` of type `void (int, int, const int (*)[col])`. *Check the difference in the third parameter of both the types*.

To fix this warning message, you can do:

```
void(*p[1])(int row, int col, const int arr[row][col]) = {min};
```

Moreover, you don't need array of function pointers if the array just contains one member. In that case you can simply do:

```
void(*p)(int row, int col, const int arr[row][col]) = min;
```